# Java webapplication - properties file nightmare

Tags: java, spring

I recently started working on a POORLY designed and developed web application.. I am finding that it uses about 300 properties files, and all the properties files are being read somewhat like this:

```
Properties prop= new Properties();
FileInputStream fisSubsSysten = new FileInputStream("whatever.properties");
prop.load(fisSubsSysten);
```

That is, it is reading the properties files from current working directory.. Another problem is the developers have chosen to use the above lines multiple times within the same java file. For example if there are 10 methods, each method will have the above code instead of having one method and calling it wherever necessary..

This means, we can NEVER change the location of the properties files, currently they are directly under the websphere profiles directory, isn't this ugly? If I move them somewhere else, and set that location in classpath, it does not work.

I tried changing the above lines like this using Spring IO utils library:

```
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("whatever.properties");
    Properties prop = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
```

But this application has over 1000 files, and I am finding it impossible to change each file.. How would you go about refactoring this mess? Is there any easy way around?

Thanks!

Comment: First, my sincere condolences. if there was some sort of worst programming nightmare contest, certainly your problem would be listed in the top 10, maybe top 5. Really, this looks like a prank. Well, in your place, maybe you could just use any other properties file loader (such as http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/ for example) and then you could try to replace everything. You'll have to check for naming clashes, probably will need to use the properties file as a new properties name prefix, etc. This can be like hell. But if moving the files is that important, I'd do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In these cases of "refactoring" i use a simple find and replace approach. Notepad++ has a " find in files" feature but there are plenty of similar programs.

Create a class which does the properties loading with a method probably with a name parameter for the property file. 
This can be a java singleton or a spring bean.

Search and replace all "new Properties()" lines with an empty line.

Replace all "load..." lines with a reference to your new class/ method. Notepad++ supports regex replacement, so you can use the filename as a parameter.

Once this is done go to eclipse and launch a "cleanup" or "organize imports" and fix some compile errors manually if needed.

This approach is quite straight forward and takes no more than 10min if you are lucky or 1 hour if you are unlucky, f.e. the code formatting is way of and each file looks different.

You can make your replace simpler if you format the project once before with a line length of 300 or more so each java statement is on one line. This makes find and replace a bit easier as you dont have newlines to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I can only agree that I find your project a bit daunting, from your reference.
However, the choice of how to maintain or improve of it is a risk that merely needs to be assessed and prioritised.

Consider building a highrise and subsequently realising the bolts that holds the infrastructure have a design flaw. The prospect of replacing them all is indeed daunting as well, so considerations into how to change them and if they really, really needs to be replaced, few, many or all.

I assume it must be a core system for the company, which somebody built and they have probably left the project (?), and you have consideration about improvement or maintaining them. But again, you must assess whether it really is important to move your property files, or if you can just for instance use symbolic links in your file system. Alternatively, do you really need to move them all or is there just a few that would really benefit from being moved. Can you just mark all places in the code with a marker  to-be-fixed-later. I sometimes mark bad classes with deprecation, and promise to fix affected classes but postpone until I have other changes in those classes until finally the deprecated class can be safely removed.

Anyway you should assess your options, leave files, replace all or partials, and provide some estimation of cost and consequences, and ask your manager which course to take.

Just note that always overestimate the solution you don't want to do, as you would be twice as likely to stop for coffee breaks, and a billboard of told-you-so's is a great leverage for decision making :)

On the technology side of your question, regex search and replace is probably the only option. I would normally put configuration files in a place accessible by classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using eclipse search feature. For example if you right click on `load()` method of the properties class and select References -> Project it will give you all location in your project where that method is used.

[image]

Also from there maybe you can attempt a global regex search and replace.